# Match node based on list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Please suggest a more informative title to this question.

I want to match a recipe based on a provided array of ingredients. If i provide the array `['tomato', celery]`, I want to match all recipes which has an ingredient whose name contains 'tomato' AND has an ingredient whose name contains 'celery'.

Today I use the following query:

```
MATCH (recipe:Recipe)
WHERE ALL(
  ingredient IN ['tomato', 'celery']
  WHERE (recipe)-[:CONTAINS_INGREDIENT]->(:Ingredient {name: ingredient})
)
RETURN recipe
```

This works, provided that the ingredients name is an exact match, but I would like it to match as long as the ingredient name CONTAINS the passed term (i.e. 'Yellow Tomatoes' would match 'tomato'), but I don't see any way to incorporate the `CONTAIN` keyword into this query.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most compact way to express this query is using a [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) and a [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension):

```
WITH ['tomato', 'celery'] AS requiredIngredients
MATCH (recipe:Recipe)
WITH
  recipe,
  size([
    (recipe)-[:CONTAINS_INGREDIENT]->(ingredient:Ingredient)
    WHERE size([requiredIngredient IN requiredIngredients WHERE ingredient.name CONTAINS requiredIngredient]) > 0
    | ingredient]
    ) AS containedRequiredIngredients,
  size(requiredIngredients) AS allRequiredIngredients
WHERE containedRequiredIngredients = allRequiredIngredients
RETURN recipe
```

The idea is to count the required ingredients (`allRequiredIngredients`) and the ones that were contained in the recipe (`containedRequiredIngredients`). If the two values are equal, the recipe is returned.

It can be tested with this example:

```
CREATE
  (r1:Recipe),
  (r1)-[:CONTAINS_INGREDIENT]->(:Ingredient {name: '50g celery (chopped)'}),
  (r1)-[:CONTAINS_INGREDIENT]->(:Ingredient {name: 'some tomato'})
```

Comment: Thank you, this is some ninja stuff, I will experiment with it! Do you believe the solution to this problem could be more elegant if I constructed the query string programmatically (in javascript in my case)?

Comment: Also I cannot run this query, "Invalid input 'W': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern"

Comment: The query runs fine in my Neo4j browser. Maybe you have an issue with escaping special chars?

Comment: W.r.t. elegance, I think this is better expressed in Cypher, than in client code, so I would not bother rewriting it in JS.

Comment: I upped the neo4j version and now your query runs w/o errors, but not as expected, if the `requiredIngredients` contains one element it matches all recipes in the database regardless of what that string is. And if I have two or more ingredients it never matches anything regardless of the content of the strings. Am I missing anything? I copy/pasted the query into the browser and only changed the array.

Comment: You're right, I made a rookie error and used `count` in the query instead of `length`. Check the updated query.